# OpenGL drawing triangles

Tags: c++, opengl

I am pretty new to OpenGL, I have followed some tutorials and now I am trying to play with it on my own. So I've got this structure:

```
struct Vertex
{
    vec3 position;
    vec3 color;
};
```

And if I have done all of this:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);
glGenBuffers(1, &vboVerticesID);

glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVerticesID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex) * mesh.vertCount, mesh.verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader["vVertex"]);
glVertexAttribPointer(shader["vVertex"], 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, position));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader["vColor"]);
glVertexAttribPointer(shader["vColor"], 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, color));
```

`mesh.vertices` is a `Vertex*` type. They are put in array that every following three forms a triangle.

The question is how do I call to render triangles? I have tried `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, mesh.vertCount);` but nothing happened, no errors thrown and no triangles rendered. Before I had separate arrays for vertices position, color and indices and `glDrawElements` was working just fine.

Mesh constructor:

```
Mesh::Mesh(const string sourcePath)
{
    ifstream modelfile;
    modelfile.open(sourcePath.c_str(), ios_base::in);

    if (!modelfile.good())
    {
        cout << "Cannot load model file (" << sourcePath << ")!\n";
    }

    string line;

    vector<vec3> tempVertices;
    vector<vec3> tempNormals;
    vector<Vertex> verticesVector;

    while (getline(modelfile, line))
    {
        if (line[0] == 'v')
        {
            if (line[1] == ' ')
            {
                vec3 v;
                sscanf_s(line.c_str(), "%*s %f %f %f", &v.x, &v.y, &v.z);
                tempVertices.push_back(v);
            }
            else if (line[1] == 'n')
            {
                vec3 n;
                sscanf_s(line.c_str(), "%*s %f %f %f", &n.x, &n.y, &n.z);
                tempNormals.push_back(n);
            }
        }
        else if (line[0] == 'f')
        {
            vector<string> elems;
            stringstream s(line);
            string item;
            while (getline(s, item, ' '))
            {
                elems.push_back(item);
            }

            if (elems.size() != 4)
            {
                cout << sourcePath << " parsing error!\n";
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i)
            {
                stringstream s(elems[i]);
                string item;
                vector<unsigned int> vs;
                while (getline(s, item, '/'))
                {
                    vs.push_back((unsigned int)atoi(item.c_str())-1);
                }

                if (vs.size() != 3)
                    cout << sourcePath << " parsing error!\n";

                Vertex vert; 
                vert.position = tempVertices[vs[0]];
                vert.color = vec3(.5f);
//              vert.normal = vs[2] != -1 ? tempNormals[vs[2]] : vec3(0.f, 1.f, 0.f);

                verticesVector.push_back(vert);
            }
        }
    }

    vertCount = verticesVector.size();
    verts = (Vertex*)malloc(vertCount * sizeof(Vertex));
    for (int i = 0; i < vertCount; ++i)
    {
        verts[i] = verticesVector[i];
        cout << verticesVector[i].position.x << " " << verticesVector[i].position.y << " " << verticesVector[i].position.z << "\n";
    }

    cout << "Model loaded(" << sourcePath << ")!\n";
}
```

Init function:

```
void OnInit()
{
    GL_CHECK_ERRORS;

    shader.LoadFromFile(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "shaders/shader.vert");
    shader.LoadFromFile(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "shaders/shader.frag");

    shader.CreateAndLingProgram();

    shader.Use();
    shader.AddAttribute("vVertex");
    shader.AddAttribute("vColor");
//  shader.AddAttribute("vNormal");
    shader.AddUniform("MVP");
//  shader.AddUniform("lightDir");
    shader.UnUse();

    GL_CHECK_ERRORS;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboVerticesID);

    glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVerticesID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex) * mesh.vertCount, mesh.verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GL_CHECK_ERRORS;

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader["vVertex"]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(shader["vVertex"], 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLubyte*)NULL + offsetof(Vertex, position));
    GL_CHECK_ERRORS;

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader["vColor"]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(shader["vColor"], 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLubyte*)NULL + offsetof(Vertex, color));
    GL_CHECK_ERRORS;

//  glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader["vNormal"]);
//  glVertexAttribPointer(shader["vNormal"], 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, normal));
//  GL_CHECK_ERRORS;

    glClearColor(.3, .3, .3, 1);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(MouseFunc);
    glutWarpPointer(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
    cout << "Initialization completed.\n" << endl;
}
```

And render function:

```
void OnRender()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    shader.Use();
    glUniformMatrix4fv(shader("MVP"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(p * v * m));
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, mesh.vertCount);
    GL_CHECK_ERRORS;
    shader.UnUse();

    glutSwapBuffers();

    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: Um, what is `shader`? I hope that's a `std::map` or something with an overloaded `[]` operator? Because it looks an awful lot to me like you are using the address of a string constant to index an array.

Comment: Also, as a general rule, do not cast the result of `offsetof` to a pointer type. That macro uses `size_t` (large enough to express any contiguous block of memory), which is not necessarily the same size as `intptr_t` (large enough to express any address). It's more portable to write `(const GLubyte *)NULL + offsetof(...)`

Comment: yes, it is `std::map` with overloaded `[]` operator. It came from this tutorial: [in2gpu](http://in2gpu.com/2015/02/25/create-a-game-engine-part-i-shader-manager/)

Comment: Okay, with that out of the way. It's possible that back-face culling is to blame here. `glDrawElements (...)` may have drawn the triangles in a different winding order. Try using `GL_POINTS` for the primitive type just to see if any vertex data at all is making it onto the GPU.

Comment: Hm, `GL_POINTS` does not helped. I think that winding order is not problem here, since I can rotate my scene. Sometimes when I do so, I can see big deformed, black face. And I have logged vertices array to console, it seems to be OK.

Comment: You are going to need to add more code to your question then, in particular code showing `mesh.verts` being allocated and filled.

Comment: OK, here is mesh constructor (it was intended to use normals as well, I comment out this until drawing is not fixed):

Comment: (Added to the code above, beacouse it was to long to fit it in comment) It reads obj file.

Comment: FYI, the libraries and techniques you are trying to use are about 20 years old. Try to find a modern tutorial.

Comment: @Mikhail: Huh? Aside from Alias Wavefront objects, everything is modern. That's really the easiest sort of file format to distribute and work with in a tutorial since parsing it isn't much work and it requires no 3rd party libraries. GLUT's the only questionable thing, but even that can get you a 3.x context in OS X if you know what you're doing.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Indeed, glut was what came to mind, and you are absolute correct, you can get GLUT running on a modern system (thats how our old games run). But its still not a good idea, especially because legacy features tend to fail silently.

Comment: i am using a freeglut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resoved it finally, all code here is OK, it was wrong use of mesh constructor (`Mesh mesh = Mesh(filePath)` instead of `Mesh mesh(filePath)`)
Thanks for help.